# Undefined JSON error in console when using .getJSON but not using embedded data

Tags: javascript, json

Could anyone help explain to me why my `console.log(tooltipValues` is coming back as undefined when the `console.log(tooltipJSON)` is populating no problem?

I'm not entirely sure why, but when I just place the data inside of my JS, it works just fine. But as soon as I export the data to a JSON file it breaks. To be clear, I can `console.log(tooltipJSON)` no problem when it's an external JSON file. Super stuck on this as I can't have embedded JSON due to it longterm holding 1000's of records.

```
var tooltipJSON;
    $.getJSON("js/tooltips.json", function (data) {
      tooltipJSON = data;

      $('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
        function() {
          var tooltipValues = tooltipJSON[$(this).data("tooltip")];    
          console.log(tooltipValues);
          console.log(tooltipJSON);

          if(!tooltipValues)return;
          var tooltip = $("<div class='tp-popup'><div>" + tooltipValues.value1 + "</div><div>" + tooltipValues.value2 + "</div></div>")
            .css({
              'color': '#fff',
              'position': 'absolute',
              'zIndex': '99999',
              'width': '100px',
              'height': '150px',
              'background-color': '#333',
            });
          $(this).append(tooltip);
          $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            $('.tp-popup').css({
              left: e.pageX,
              top: e.pageY,
            });
          });
        },
        function() {
          $('.tp-popup').remove();
        }
      ); 
    });
```

EXTERNAL JSON USED IN THE ABOVE:

```
[
  {
    "skill-one": {
        "value1": "skill-one value1",
        "value2": "skill-one value2",
        "value3": "skill-one value3"
    },
    "trinket-two": {
        "value1": "trinket-two value1",
        "value2": "trinket-two value2",
        "value3": "trinket-two value3"
    }
  }
]
```

This returns with no issues though?

```
tooltipJSON = {
    "skill-one": {
      "value1": "skill-one value1",
      "value2": "skill-one value2",
      "value3": "skill-one value3"
    },
    "trinket-two": {
      "value1": "trinket-two value1",
      "value2": "trinket-two value2",
      "value3": "trinket-two value3"
    },
}
$('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
        function() {
          var tooltipValues = tooltipJSON[$(this).data("tooltip")];    
          console.log(tooltipValues);
          console.log(tooltipJSON);

          if(!tooltipValues)return;
          var tooltip = $("<div class='tp-popup'><div>" + tooltipValues.value1 + "</div><div>" + tooltipValues.value2 + "</div></div>")
            .css({
              'color': '#fff',
              'position': 'absolute',
              'zIndex': '99999',
              'width': '100px',
              'height': '150px',
              'background-color': '#333',
            });
          $(this).append(tooltip);
          $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            $('.tp-popup').css({
              left: e.pageX,
              top: e.pageY,
            });
          });
        },
        function() {
          $('.tp-popup').remove();
        }
      );
```

This is the code to focus on, for whatever reason `console.log(tooltipValues);` doesn't work with the external JSON, but the console log of the JSON itself works and populates no issues. Note that both consoles.log's work with embedded internal JSON.

```
$('.skill, .trinket, .hero').hover(
        function() {
          var tooltipValues = tooltipJSON[$(this).data("tooltip")];    
          console.log(tooltipValues);
          console.log(tooltipJSON);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Instead of `$(this).data("tooltip")` ?

Comment: It seems that in the first case `$(this).data("tooltip")` is not defined. Can you log this value in both cases and check that the entry is in the `data` parameter? A snippet or a fiddle link would help.

Comment: @JavierRey, `data("tooltip")` is in both instances(using external JSON and embedded JSON). It's in my HTML tags as data-tooltip. For example : `<div class="skill s-inner col-xs-1" data-tooltip="skill-one" >`

Comment: Also, I didn't want to provide HTML, etc... because it's obviously an issue with the external JSON call or the .getJSON method I'm using. Everything works no issue with the embedded JSON data, it's only when I convert it to external data.

Comment: If `data("tooltip")` is correct and present in `tooltipJSON` in both cases, the only thing I can think of is an ecoding problem with the file `js/tooltips.json`. Try to save it with a text editor like Notepad++, setting the encoding as UTF-8 without BOM. Or maybe just the Notepad, saving as UTF-8. Also, remove the last `comma` in your JSON content, it can be a syntax error.

Comment: when you `console.log(tooltipJSON);` is the output an object like the hardcoded version, or is it a string?

Comment: it's an object. And my code all works when the code is embedded, it's only when I place it in an external JSON file that all of a sudden it doesn't work. But to be clear here, I can still console.log the JSON as an external file, it's only when I do the data("tooltip) portion and all of a sudden the JSON comes back as undefined.

Comment: making a plunker atm.

Comment: I added an edit to show the block of code I'm having issues with. Also, fake out on the plunker, it doesn't work with jquery for some reason. Jsfiddle and everything else don't allow 'external' files unless it's already hosted somewhere. With Plunker I could make a .json file.

Comment: @ObsidianAge jQuery's `$.getJSON` has already parsed the response into an object. Using `JSON.parse` would result in an error

Comment: @dbrree check your browser's *Network* console and inspect the JSON response. Make sure it looks correct

Comment: Added the JSON that's in the external file. Nothing changes aside from that. If I revert back to the embedded internal JSON, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's `getJSON` method works differently across different JQuery versions, giving silent errors unless you implement the `fail` callback. You have a trailing `comma` before the end of your JSON content that is causing the method to fail. Also, I was using JQuery 2.1 and the method did not show anything. I upgraded to version [3.1.1](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js) and then traced and fixed the error. Below is the relevant code of my test.

```
var tooltipJSON;
$.getJSON("js/tooltips.json", function (data) {
  tooltipJSON = data;
  console.log("data", data);
  var key = $(this).data("tooltip"), tooltipValues = tooltipJSON[key];
  console.log("'"+key+"'", tooltipValues);
}).fail(function (err) {
  console.log("error", err);
});
```

The external JSON should be an object `{...}` rather than an array containing an object `[{...}]`:

```
{
  "skill-one": {
    "value1": "skill-one value1",
    "value2": "skill-one value2",
    "value3": "skill-one value3"
  },
  "trinket-two": {
    "value1": "trinket-two value1",
    "value2": "trinket-two value2",
    "value3": "trinket-two value3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, no clue what's up man. Shit is still undefined. As soon as I revert back to embedded json though it works perfectly fine.

Comment: the `console.log("data", data);` works, but anything past that point still shows as undefined. I'll edit my original post with my external JSON file so you can see that there is nothing wrong with it. This is making me LOSE MY MIND.

Comment: But the external JSON file is an array, rather than a plain object. Remove the enclosing brackets `[{...}]` and leave only the braces `{...}` see above.

Comment: Boom, can't BELIEVE that was the problem. Been losing my mind for the past two days over this.

Comment: Finally. Congrats!